# custom backgrounds not animating on view change

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have custom background for my standard view and my grouped uitableview which I have declared in

//RooViewController

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO]; //Hides the navigation bar

    //Add custom background
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.parentViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]];

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

//GroupedTableviewController

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{      
    //Add custom background
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.parentViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgplain.png"]];

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

The thing with this is the views just disappear and reappear but there is an animation happening between the views sliding left to right... how can I add these custom backgrounds to this view change animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a background view of the view that's appearing, not the view of the parent view controller.  By setting the view of the parent view controller you're essentially switching out that view (which won't be animate) while the view of the appearing view controller (which is clear, apparently) is animated in.  Instead, add the background view to the appearing view controller view, or in your case, just set the color:

`self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgplain.png"]];`

I also noted that you've changing the background view of the parentView in your root view controller, which means the parent view is probably a UINavigationView (also per your comment).  In general, you shouldn't be changing the view characteristics of a navigationController mostly because it's designed to hold other views/controllers, not display its own view (besides the navigation bar, of course).

So I don't think you should be messing with `self.parentViewController.view` and stick with `self.view` in each view controller.

Comment: thank you for your reply.. this almost suites my needs.. however I guess I should have mentioned that the tableview is also inside a navigationcontroller.. and this solution is messing with that navigation controller bar. when the view changes with the animation the bar goes white

Comment: I've added some clarification to my answer. See if that helps.

Comment: okay cool, I get what your saying.. kinda, I mean this is a slightly confusing topic. I started using the self.view for both views.. however sounds like I might not be supposed to  change stuff.. also in regards to the navigation controller I have declared that inside the appdelegate "MainWindow.xib"

Comment: View Controllers can be a confusing subject when you first start out.  Accessing self.view is perfectly fine.  But if you're using IB to create those views, it'll be easier to set all your background view characteristics there, rather than in code.  To be honest, I never use IB (I always create the view controllers with code), but it's usually a good idea to stick with one or the other.  Also I highly recommend reading this...all of it: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457

Comment: thanks, looks like some good reading..I have read a few of the articles in the developer library but not this one.. thanks for pointing it out :)